# Accessibility of autosave fields

Tags: forms, input, onblur, uiaccessibility

I've got a profile screen with a few simple text and radio button fields. I want to avoid submit button but instead autosave the value of the field onblur event. That approach is becoming more and more common but I am wondering how to resolve that from the accessibility point of view - especially for the text reader viewers. How to inform them that the fields have that autosave functionality in the most effective and convenient way? Should I just add approriate information in `aria-label` or maybe there is a better way to do that?